# Cannot Run even Basic Script in Visual Studio Code due to pop-up Recommendations prompt. Using C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

So I've downloaded visual studio code to use for Unity development. I have installed all the necessary prerequisites on their "how-to" page. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled them several times. When I try to run a script, instead of the script running, it gives me the options to select what environment I'm using and gives me recommendations to install c# debuggers, even though I already have them installed. I don't understand what to do at this point. I've also noticed when typing keywords it only autocomplete some of the ones I want and not all of them, even though I have all of them installed.

Here's the most basic script you can have in c# as a test run.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print("hello World!");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
    {
        
    }

 }
```

but when I run the script it does this. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem so I can actually begin coding in visual studio code.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbSOr.png][1]

Comment: You need to run the code in unity. Not in vs code.

Comment: Also, you probably want 'Debug.Log("Hello World");' vs print.  Although maybe print is supported too nowadays?

Comment: @EddieParker [`print`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour-print.html) is basically a shortkey to `Debug.Log` ;) It was added years ago and at least already existed back in [`5.2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour-print.html) (that' how far the API goes back) so depends a bit on your definition of "nowadays" but yeah ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you go to unity there it's a play button at the top and centered, with a pause button next to it. The play button is for running all the scripts that you made.
As for VS code not completing you keywords, try using the original visual studio, just make sure when installing to include "game development with unity" for visual studio to recognize unity